# How to retrieve all of one table and all joined records in another with the other table's columns in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to retrieve all of one table and all joined records in another.

I would like to have all columns from both tables

This is extremely simple in SQL

e.g.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM students
JOIN teachers
ON students.id = teachers.student_id
```

How can I do the same in rails?

I've tried variations on

```rb
Student.includes(:teacher)
```

and

```rb
Student.joins(:teacher).includes(:teacher)
```

The join is working, but I cannot access columns from Teacher table

Note that the end goal is simply to be able to create an instance variable in the controller so that I can access **both** student and teacher data in the view

Comment: Could you be more specific about the `cannot access columns` part? Are you using the `teacher` table to make a query conditions?

Comment: @HDox what is returned from the queries as they currently stand simply doesn't have both tables' data (just one). So, for example `@data = Student.joins(:teacher)` then when I attempt `@data.years_employed` it errors, since `years_employed` comes from the teacher table (which isn't included in the @data). @data only contains the data from the `students` table

Comment: Try `data = Student.joins(:teacher).select('teacher.years_employed')`
Then `data.first.years_employed` would give you the years employed for that particular teacher.

Answer (score 1):

`Student.includes(:teacher)` will return `ActiveRecord::CollectionProxy` which means if take particular object in this collection, it will be `Student` class object.

Unlike sql query fired and returning data from 2 tables, it does not work same in rails, you get data only from `students` column which will relate associated record in `teachers` table because it represent `Student` model.

You can access further `teachers` data like,

```
  students = Student.includes(:teacher)
  students.last.teacher.name
```

In above no new query will get fired in database when you call `teacher` association on object